# Why are dynamic backends on Google AppEngine not auto scaling?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Why are dynamic backends on Google AppEngine not auto scaling when I have defined my backend as dynamic and my task queue is configured with a high processing rate?

My application needs to perform large CSV file (100,000 plus record) data loads to the datastore.  To achieve this I am using a Backend to read the file and then drop the records on to a task queue on the same backend so the records can be written to the datastore in parallel.  I have setup my queue the following way:

```
<queue>
    <name>product-dataload</name>
    <rate>30/s</rate>
    <bucket-size>40</bucket-size>
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-retry-limit>2</task-retry-limit>
    </retry-parameters>
</queue>
```

My Backend is defined the following way:

```
<backend name="dataloader">
    <class>B1</class>
    <options>
        <dynamic>true</dynamic>
    </options>
</backend>
```

What I observe is that only one backend instance of "dataloader" is created.  The backend instance CPU runs at about 35% to 45% with QPS around 10s and latency of 225ms, but the Task Queue shows an Enforced Rate of 15/s rather than my defined 30/s.  It's as if the app engine scheduler doesn't realize I am set to dynamic and it is forcing the rate to 15/s to deal with just one instance.  As a test, I changed my backend definition to define 4 instances rather than being dynamic.  When I run the dataload, all 4 instances receive traffic and my enforced rate stays at 30/s rather than throttling to 15s and my through put goes up (QPS around 7.5 per instance and latency of 310ms)  I really want the dataloads to run as fast as possible so I am willing to have a large number of instances turned on to process as many records in parallel as possible and I would like the instances shut off when they complete.

Has anyone seen similar issues - can anyone at Google comment?